# Uwsgi server must execute in script path else I get a http 500 response

Tags: uwsgi

I can't understand why I am getting a http 500 response. When I run my uwsgi server from the path that my python script is defined in, everything is perfect. As soon as I run it from another path, I get a 500 response.

Here is my uwsgi script (I set the protocol to http just for testing purposes):

```
/home/baz/.virtualenvs/python-flask-benchmark/bin/uwsgi 
--master
--socket 127.0.0.1:3031 
--pythonpath "/home/baz/Personal/Github/benchmark-node_vs_python/python"
--file "/home/baz/Personal/Github/benchmark-node_vs_python/python/app.py" 
--callable app 
--processes 20 
--virtualenv "/home/baz/.virtualenvs/python-flask-benchmark" 
--enable-threads 
--protocol http
```

Does anyone know why? It seems like it is ignoring the `--pythonpath` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. It was a path error whereby my application could not find a file to open. The problem was that this was not logged to Uwsgi, which was just silent. The reason was because this was a flask application, which needs to be instructed to pass all exception errors to uwsgi by doing this: `app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True`